# Calculating a sum of numbers in C shell

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I'm trying to calculate a sum numbers positioned on separate lines using C shell.

I must do it with specific commands using pipes.

There is a number of commands: `comand.. | comand.. | (comands...)`
printing lines in the following form:

```
1
2
8
4
7
```

The result should be **22**, since `1 + 2 + 8 + 4 + 7 = 22`.

I tried `... | bc | tr "\n" "+" | bc`, but it didn't work.

I can't use AWK, or variables. That is why I am asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can use the C shell variables, as they are part of the syntax. Without using variables, you need to pipe, and pipe again:

```
your-command | sed '2~1 s/^/+/' | xargs | bc
```

The `sed` command prepends plus character to all lines starting from the second; `xargs` joins the lines as a sequence of arguments.

The SED expression can be improved to filter out non-numeric lines:

```
'/^[^0-9]\+$/ d; 2~1 s/\([0-9]\+\)/+\1/'
```